# Django: select data from 2 models

Tags: django, django-models

Good day!

I have 2 models and I am trying to get sql equivalent of : select * from both models where order=xx. Appreciate little assistance :)

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ResourcePool(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    item_a = models.CharField()
    item_b = models.CharField()
    item_c = models.CharField()
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
```

Tried the following, but it does not inlude fields from 'Orders' model

```
ResourcePool.objects.filter(order_id__pk=26).values()
ResourcePool.objects.filter(order_id__pk=26).select_related().values()
```

Comment: so what problem are you facing?

Comment: Data from Orders is missing, I need to include *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResourcePool.objects.filter(order_id__pk=26).values('orders__created','email','item_a',item_b','item_c')
```

try this

Comment: The foreign key is `order_id` so it would be `order_id__created` not `orders__created`.

Comment: Following provides field from other model ONLY, I need data from both models, like a table join, how can I do that please ?
    ResourcePool.objects.filter(order_id__pk=26).values('order_id__created')

The following errors out
    ResourcePool.objects.filter(order_id__pk=26).values('order_id__created').select_related()
TypeError: Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list()

Comment: edited my ans @user1619524 check it, hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yes thank you, it works, thought I have to provide all fields, is there a wild card pattern. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome bro, see the thing is when you are using Orders model to query then you need to pass ResourcePool in all small with 2 underscore and the field name, thats how it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
order = Orders.objects.get(pk=26)
resource=ResourcePool.objects.filter(order_id=order.id).select_related()
```

And to obtain the data of "Orders"

```
id_order_pk26 = resource.order_id.order_id
created_pk26 = resource.order_id.created
```